# Create pandas dataframe from complex string

Tags: python, json, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a string like this:

[image]

I would like to achieve something like this:

| timestamp | series_0 | series_1 | series_2 | series_3 | series_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-02T12:06:00Z | 0.17167550325393677 | 0.6362519860267639 | 0.8500638604164124 | 0.574917733669281 |  |
| 2021-01-02T12:59:00Z | 0.28116047382354736 | 0.6466034054756165 | 0.14291030168533325 | 0.05188792943954468 |  |

For each timestamp and variable the contribution score.

Comment: Hi Luca, I tried to update the formatting of your question. Please check if I missed some data in the table or not -- it seems like there are no values for series_4

Comment: Please provide the initial string as text. Screenshots are not copyable.

Comment: string is like this:
{'timestamp': '2021-01-02T12:06:00Z',
  'value': {'contributors': [{'contributionScore': 0.8500638604164124,
     'variable': 'series_2'},
    {'contributionScore': 0.6362519860267639, 'variable': 'series_1'},
    {'contributionScore': 0.6200128197669983, 'variable': 'series_3'},
    {'contributionScore': 0.574917733669281, 'variable': 'series_4'},
    {'contributionScore': 0.17167550325393677, 'variable': 'series_0'}],
   'isAnomaly': True,
   'severity': 0.3320668339729309,
   'score': 0.5705844163894653},
  'errors': []},

Comment: @CallumDA it's ok, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all your data , but I tried this and it works

```
import pandas as pd

result =  {
    'timestamp': '2021-01-02T12:06:00Z', 
    'value': 
        {
          'contributors': [
                           {'contributionScore': 0.8500638604164124, 'variable': 'series_2'}, 
                           {'contributionScore': 0.6362519860267639, 'variable': 'series_1'}, 
                           {'contributionScore': 0.6200128197669983, 'variable': 'series_3'}, 
                           {'contributionScore': 0.574917733669281, 'variable': 'series_4'},
                           {'contributionScore': 0.17167550325393677, 'variable': 'series_0'}],
          'isAnomaly': True,
          'severity': 0.3320668339729309, 
          'score': 0.5705844163894653
         }, 
   'errors': []
   }


data = {
    
    'timestamp' : [result['timestamp']],
    'series_0'  : [result['value']['contributors'][4]['contributionScore']],
    'series_1'  : [result['value']['contributors'][1]['contributionScore']],
    'series_2'  : [result['value']['contributors'][0]['contributionScore']],
    'series_3'  : [result['value']['contributors'][2]['contributionScore']],
    'series_4'  : [result['value']['contributors'][3]['contributionScore']]
    
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(df)
```

Output :

```
   timestamp  series_0  series_1  series_2  series_3  series_4
0  2021-01-02T12:06:00Z  0.171676  0.636252  0.850064  0.620013  0.574918
```

This will work if your initial string has the same structure as my result variable

Can you give all your string as text ?

Comment: If I try your code I have this error "TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3790163814597238> in <module>
      4 data = {
      5 
----> 6     'timestamp' : [result['timestamp']],
      7     'series_0'  : [result['value']['contributors'][4]['contributionScore']],
      8     'series_1'  : [result['value']['contributors'][1]['contributionScore']],

TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: Because your String doesn't have the same structure , Can you give me all your String as text

Comment: [{'timestamp': '2021-01-02T12:06:00Z',
  'value': {'contributors': [{'contributionScore': 0.8500638604164124,
     'variable': 'series_2'},
    {'contributionScore': 0.6362519860267639, 'variable': 'series_1'},
    {'contributionScore': 0.6200128197669983, 'variable': 'series_3'},
    {'contributionScore': 0.574917733669281, 'variable': 'series_4'},
    {'contributionScore': 0.17167550325393677, 'variable': 'series_0'}],
   'isAnomaly': True,
   'severity': 0.3320668339729309,
   'score': 0.5705844163894653},
  'errors': []},